# Wrong button is clicked on with a page having two buttons

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver to test a web page. 
The web page http://www.leaseplan.nl/contact/index.asp has two buttons, one button with button text 'Zoeken' and one with button text 'Verstuur'. I want to click on the button with button text 'Verstuur' either by using XPath or CssSelector with the following code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/form/fieldset/a/span")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("fieldset.contact_form > a.button > span.button_center")).Click();
```

But using the either one of the above lines of code, on the button with text 'Zoeken' is clicked on instead.

This button has quite a similar CssSelector and XPath:

```
fieldset.header_search a.button span.button_center

/html/body/div[3]/div/form/fieldset/a/span[2]
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out with the cssSelector and tell me if it's work.
For "verstuur" :

`By.cssSelector("div.content form a.button")`

**Solution :**

Ok, i've found your problem. Your xpath is good but now, your action on the click submit the first form, so the form with "Zoeken".

```
onclick="document.forms[0].submit();" // submit the 1st form, the bad one !
```

Try this :

```
onclick="document.forms["form"].submit();" // submit the 2nd form, the good one !
//or
onclick="document.forms[1].submit();"
```

proof : [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwhu4/3/)

Comment: Hi, I've tried the above, but still the button with button text 'Zoeken' is clicked on . Here the line of code: driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.content form a.button")).Click();

Comment: So, i suggest to you to try like this   By.cssSelector("div.content form[name='form'] a.button")

Comment: Hi, tried this as well and still the other button is clicked on. It seems that the first button found on the page is clicked on and the CssSelector is ignored.

Comment: did you try to catch element by element going step by step ? like do the xpath("//form[@name='form']") exists ? do the xpath("//form[@name='form']/a") exists  ? and going deeper eachtime ?

Comment: I've run test with all of the following xpaths:                 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[@name='form']"));
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[@name='form']/fieldset"));
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[@name='form']/fieldset/a"));
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[@name='form']/fieldset/a/span[2]")); and all work fine. But when adding Click() to the last xpath, still the other button 'Zoeken' is clicked on. The relative xpath of the button 'Zoeken' is the same except for the name of the form. It seems that the name of the form is not taken into account

Comment: Kinda weird..Have you tried to change the name of the form ? what's the value when you type this `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[@name='form']/fieldset/a/span[2]")).getText();`

Comment: I get the following error when adding getText(): Error 1 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement' does not contain a definition for 'gettext' and no extension method 'gettext' accepting a first argument of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). The Selenium test script is in c#, do you happen to know which assembly reference I need for gettext ?

Comment: Followed by that [link](http://www.seleniumwiki.com/webdriver/creating-gettext-function-for-selenium-2-in-c-sharp/), you can use `.Text`

Comment: I've added your getText method and the text 'VERSTUUR' is returned. So the xpath is correct. But still the other button is clicked on, quite strange.

Comment: Apprently, this is not a problem with the link. But with your action  `onclick="document.forms[0].submit();"`

Comment: @user2240004 i've edited my original post with a solution. try and tell me !

Comment: The website that I'm testing is not mine. I solely use it to gain experience with Selenium. I can't change the source of the page. Or do I need to add this line of code to my script ?

Answer (score 0):

xpath for ZOEKEN `/html/body/div[3]/div/form/fieldset/a/span[2]`

xpath for VERSTUUR `/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/form/fieldset/a/span[2]`

Comment: Hi HemChe, the XPath I have for both buttons. Even though they're different, the button 'Zoeken' is found and clicked on.

Comment: I have now tried to find the element with driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span:contains('Verstuur')")).Click(); but then I get the error message 'Unable to find element with css selector == span:contains('Verstuur'). Any idea what is wrong with it ? The html of the element I'm trying to find is <span class="button_center">Verstuur</span>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='Verstuur']")).click();
```

Edit:

I think you want to learn Selenium that's why you are using 3rd party websites. If you really want to learn Selenium find some opensource applications to automate. Here is a good application to automate - 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/sugarcrm/files/1%20-%20SugarCRM%206.5.X/FastStack/

Download the latest version and install.

Find more info about the website and selenium stuff here. It's so good..

http://selftechy.com/2011/02/05/introduction-to-selenium-web-application-test-automation-tool

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, still the other button with button text 'Zoeken' is clicked on. I have now tried to find the element with driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span:contains('Verstuur')")).Click(); but then I get the error message 'Unable to find element with css selector == span:contains('Verstuur'). Any idea what is wrong with it ? The html of the element I'm trying to find is <span class="button_center">Verstuur</span>

Comment: Try driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form[1]//span[text()='Verstuur']")).click();

Answer (score 0):

Zoeken: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[1]/form/fieldset/a/span[2]")).click();`

Verstuur : `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/form/fieldset/a/span[2]")).click();`

Using xpath is easy but slow.