# Not able to Click a Link in Gmail using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am a learner.
I am trying to automate the logout functionality of Gmail using Selenium Webdriver but unable to do so ..

There are two Phases in logout, first click the Right Link at the top, if that box appears then click logout. iam unable to do so.

```
<span id="gbi4t" style="max-width: 76px; text-align: left;">Mahmood Ali</span>

<a id="gb_71" class="gbqfbb" href="?logout&hl=en&hlor" onclick="gbar.logger.il(9,{l:'o'})" role="button" target="_top">Sign out</a>
```

here is my xpath

```
//*[@id="gbi4t"] -> Clicking that top to get the logout pop up

//*[@id="gb_71"] -> To logout the gmail application
```

i have tried such as

```
driver.findElement(By.id("gbi4t")).click();   OR

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gbi4t']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.id("gb_71")).click();  OR

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gb_71']")).click();
```

Some ideas out there ?

Comment: Not able to identify the element.

Comment: user1177636 is right, dont work on gmail as a beginner, there are some open source web apps to do this, see my answer here,- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785962/wrong-button-is-clicked-on-with-a-page-having-two-buttons/15787796#15787796

Comment: got the error  org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"gbi4t"}
Command duration or timeout: 3.03 seconds

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me user2087450, surely i will try simple examples, first i will complete this and proceed to the simple example

Comment: possible duplicate of [selenium webdriver to find the anchor tag and click that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773944/selenium-webdriver-to-find-the-anchor-tag-and-click-that)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `<span>` isn't recognized as an element.

You need to use the `<a id="gbg4" ...>` to `click()` on it, wait the pop up and click on the `<a id="gb_71" class="gbqfbb" ...>` to logout.

I let you code, since you need to pracctice :P

tell me what's up.

**Suggestions :**

What i can suggest to you is to use the `cssSelector()`.

why ? Because it's faster than the xpath and when page like google or others use dynamic value used for id/name it's better to use the class attribute and `cssSelector()` is way better than others.

But sometimes you'll use xpath to find an element that has "cancel" as inner text (exemple : `<a>cancel</a>` )

[cssSelector() reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Thanks for replying e1che i dint understand the <a id="gbg4" ...> to click() and also <a id="gb_71" class="gbqfbb" ...> to logout. i got the css and dont know how to use                [   html.aAX body.aAU div div.nH div.nH div.nH div.nH div#gb.gbes div#gbw div#gbu.gbes div#gbvg.gbvg ol.gbtc li.gbt a#gbg6.gbgt span#gbi4t]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try following:

```
driver.find_element(:id, "gbgs4dn").click
driver.find_element(:id, "gb_71").click
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks 4 reply Hi grm it dint work for me, also can you please tell me where is gbgs4dn located[<span id="gbi4t" style="max-width: 76px; text-align: left;">Mahmood Ali</span>]

Comment: In my above case, my account doesn't have 'Notifications' & 'Google share' buttons in the row where we click to get 'Sing out' popup. In your case, you've 'Notifications' & 'Google share' buttons. You can try: driver.find_element(:id, "gbi4t").click & then driver.find_element(:id, "gb_71").click

Answer (score 0):

This code certainly works for me:

```
  // (after logging to google.com)
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("gbi4t")));
  //open overlay
driver.findElement(By.id("gbi4t")).click();  
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("gb_71")));
  //press logout
driver.findElement(By.id("gb_71")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a solved example ::

```
package testme;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class testexample {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static WebElement element;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        //setting the chrome driver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/workspace/Downloads/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();


        driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");

        element =driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign in"));
        element.click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));
        element.sendKeys("yourusername@gmail.com");
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd"));
        element.sendKeys("yourpassword");
        element.submit();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //click on the logout link step 1
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/a"));
        element.click();
        // click on actual logout button step 2
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("gb_71"));
        element.click();
        //closing the webdriver window after successful completion of the test
        driver.close();
        }
    }
```